# Is there a way to test an accessor method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I gave a `getFooAttribute` method that returns a value depending on the format of some field.

```
public function getFooAttribute() 
{
    $re = 'some regex /';
    if(preg_match($re, $this->bar) === 1){
        return 'normal'. $this->bar;
    }
    return 'not normal'. $this->bar;
}
```

Now I would like to write tests for when a field is a certain value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [test case](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/testing#main-content) like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function test_foo_attribute()
{
    $model = YourModel::factory()->make();

    $model->bar = 'should be normal';
    $this->assertTrue(Str::startsWith($model->bar, 'normal'));

    $model->bar = 'should be not normal';
    $this->assertTrue(Str::startsWith($model->bar, 'not normal'));
}
```

Comment: I would say that you test is not exactly right, you don't have to use `Str::startsWith` but literally write the whole string you expect, because if the code is wrong and you are getting `normal`, but then whatever, you are not asserting that and the test will still pass

Comment: I think I get the idea, let me try it out.